# 90% zoom on browser makes no media query used

Tags: css, media-queries

I wrote CSS media queries to deal with the the width of a class:

```
@media (max-width:1920px) {
    .slides {
        width: 860px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1500px) {
    .slides {
        width: 852px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1280px) {
    .slides {
        width: 850px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1097px) {
    .slides {
        width: 680px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:960px) {
    .slides {
        width: 540px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .slides {
        width: 410px;
    }
}
```

All of these media queries are hitting the browser from the zoom 500% to 100%. But once I get to 90% none of them are being applied. Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `90%` zoom your page probably has more than `1920px`, which is why none of your queries apply. You don't have a default case. You could add, for example:

```
.slides {
    width: 960px;
}
```

before all your queries. Of course, you should change `960px` to the desired width of your `.slides` when on screens wider than `1920px`.

On a `1920px` monitor, at `90%`, the page's width is `~2133px`. At `50%` it will have `3840px` and so on...

If you want your `.slides` to be a percentage of your screen, use `vw` (1vw = {viewport width}/100). For example, this will make your `.slides` 50% of your viewports' width, no matter the zoom level (unless a stronger rule applies, of course):

```
.slides {
     width: 50vw;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this now applies it. But how do you distinguish 90% zoom from 75%? This is applied to both.

Comment: Inspect your page when zoomed at each level. You will see the `width` of your viewport is different, depending on the actual width of your monitor. You can set levels even for 10%, that making your page's width 10x your monitor actual size in pixels.